# How to arrange overlapping buttons in Android xml layout?

Tags: android, xml-layout

In my layout there are three buttons and want to set PNG images for the buttons background but, the buttons overlap a little bit on one another. I want to how arrange the button in my layout. Which layout would be better for me in this context. You can see image of the layout below, that I want to develop. Please help me in this respect; your help would be cordially appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In your image,button have no overlap.

Comment: this is the visible area of the buttons and the backgrounds of the buttons are transparent that overlap

Comment: Now you may check the image again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all 3 buttons in a container, for example a `RelativeLayout`.
The center button (big one) would be aligned as "centerHorizontal=true". The left and right buttons would be aligned as "alignParentLeft=true", and respectively "alignParentRight=true". Plus, both buttons to have some margins on top.

I believe you can achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can use `AbstractLayout`,although it is `deprecated`.